# Complex Integration of Improper Integrals

Tags: complex-integration

I need to calculate the integration using Cauchy's Residue Theorem
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx$$

I am stuck here how can I approach this.

$$\int_{Cr}^{} f(z) dz = 0$$.

I need to show that the function is zero using Jordan's Lemma.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use the inequality $|\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz|\le \max_{z\in\Gamma} |f(z)| \cdot \text{length}(\Gamma)$.